# Hub and spoke map

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, mapping, free-software

I have a bunch of addresses located in a city, there is a central location which is the hub and I'm looking to create a hub and spoke map with lines coming from the hub and going to every point on the map. The best example I can think of is like the airline route maps with flight paths extending from the hubs. Does anyone know of any software (preferably) free that can be used to create a map in this style?

Comment: Well, as far as free software goes, you're going to want to download QGIS. I've never made such a map but I'm sure it's doable through QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any GIS software can do this. One excellent free option is [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/).**

I recommend the latest *long-term* release version (LTR), rather than the latest release. The LTR is usually less buggy. Everytime you run QGIS it will recommend updating to the latest release; you can ignore those reminders. But do occasionally check the download page to see if there's a bug-fixing update to the LTR (eg updating from version 3.4.10 to 3.4.11).

**QGIS has a tool called `Join by lines (hub lines)`.**

[image]

[image]

It took me less time to create dummy data and make hub lines than it did to write this answer.

If you want curved hub lines like airline route maps usually have, it's a bit more involved, but doable using the arrow line style. See this question for details: [Making lines curvy using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/215484/81764)

Also check out this related question for other software suggestions: [Mapping matrix of origins and destinations in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27264/81764)